# Is there a way to make iTunes automatically sync with Apple's device?

Tags: windows, com, winapi, itunes, synchronization

I am finding a way if I can write a Win32 application to sync media files into iTunes library and then use this Win32 application to launch iTunes to sync the new library to the Apple device.

Is there any COM or other libraries operate like that?

Comment: Sounds like two distinct questions/problems.  Are you asking for help with both, or just the second (syncing to the device)?

Comment: Now I could sync the media files into itunes library. But after that, I cannot instantly tell iTunes to sync with Apple's device.

Answer (score 0):

As half an answer, could you not add the media files into the itunes library.xml file directly?...Then you'd still need to get itunes to sync with the device...

Comment: You mean if my way to add media files to iTunes lib is to modify library.xml, I still have to manually press the "synchronize" button on iTunes to sync with the device ?

Comment: Not knowing the iTunes api, that is where you currently end up with my solution.  There may be some way of programmatically getting itunes to sync, but I'm not familiar with the api